# Mongo find unique results

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

What's the easiest way to get all the documents from a collection that are unique based on a single field.

I know I can use db.collections.distrinct to get an array of all the distinct values of a field, but I want to get the first (or really any one) document for every distinct value of one field.

e.g. if the database contained:

```
{number:1, data:'Test 1'}
{number:1, data:'This is something else'}
{number:2, data:'I'm bad at examples'}
{number:3, data:'I guess there\'s room for one more'}
```

it would return (based on `number` being unique:

```
{number:1, data:'Test 1'}
{number:2, data:'I'm bad at examples'}
{number:3, data:'I guess there\'s room for one more'}
```

Edit: I should add that the server is running Mongo 2.0.8 so no aggregation and there's more results than group will support.

Comment: Upgrade to 2.4 and use aggregation :)

Comment: You may find that aggregated results, even if they were supported on the version you are using, may not support the size of result set you need either.

Comment: @Philipp if only it were that easy to get it upgraded.

@MustafaGenç how would I use distinct?  I think that can only five me something like `[1,2,3]`

@WiredPrairie Currently I'm thinking ~150k results, but I'm expecting it to grow...

Comment: @TomKiley It was quite easy for me: shut down mongod, copy the binaries, restart mongod. But that was in my private testing environment. When you use sharding and authentication [there is a bit more you have to do](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-upgrade/). But I also know how much red tape can be involved when you are working for a large enterprise and try to update some "mission-critical" software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to 2.4 and use aggregation :)

When you really need to stick to the old version of MongoDB due to too much red tape involved, you could use [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/).

In MapReduce, the map function transforms each document of the collection into a new document and a distinctive key. The reduce function is used to merge documents with the same distincitve key into one.

Your map function would emit your documents as-is and with the number-field as unique key. It would look like this:

```
 var mapFunction = function(document) {
      emit(document.number, document);
 }
```

Your reduce-function receives arrays of documents with the same key, and is supposed to somehow turn them into one document. In this case it would just discard all but the first document with the same key:

```
var reduceFunction = function(key, documents) {
    return documents[0];
}
```

Unfortunately, MapReduce has some problems. It can't use indexes, so at least two javascript functions are executed for every single document in the collections (it can be limited by pre-excluding some documents with the query-argument to the mapReduce command). When you have a large collection, this can take a while. You also can't fully control how the docments created by MapReduce are formed. They always have two fields, `_id` with the key and `value` with the document you returned for the key.

MapReduce is also hard to debug an troubleshoot.

**tl;dr:** Update to 2.4

Comment: Thanks for setting up the mapreduce for me.  Sounds like I'll still have to do some post-processing to reformat the returned documents.  Upgrading is definitely on the todo list.